# Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll

Tags: .net, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I was trying to execute a simple select query using efcore 2.1 and the output window throws multiple exception

> "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll"

but will eventually run the query. what is causing this?

Also this happens only when i include more than one related entities, for example the first two queries will run without any problem but the last one will throw a exception in the output.

```
 var a = _projectDbContext.Tasks.Where(x => x.Id == taskId)
          .Include(x => x.TaskType)             
          .FirstOrDefault();
        var b = _projectDbContext.Tasks.Where(x => x.Id == taskId)            
            .Include(x => x.TaskStatus)
          .FirstOrDefault();
        var c = _projectDbContext.Tasks.Where(x => x.Id == taskId)
          .Include(x => x.TaskType)
            .Include(x => x.TaskStatus)
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

[here the output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R65T7.png)

My actual query throw these exception multiple time and slowing down the execution.

```
public partial class Tasks
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }      
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }      
    public Guid? TaskTypeId { get; set; }        
    public Guid? TaskStatusId { get; set; }       
    public TaskStatus TaskStatus { get; set; }
    public TaskTypes TaskType { get; set; }

}
public partial class TaskTypes
{
    public TaskTypes()
    {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Tasks>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }   
    public string TypeName { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
}
public partial class TaskStatus
{
    public TaskStatus()
    {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Tasks>();
    }    
    public Guid Id { get; set; }      
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What types are TaskType and TaskStatus?  Can you post those properties, an outlien of all related classes and any fluent configurations?

Comment: Because TaskStatus doesn't sound like an Entity name.

Comment: @bommelding updated the post with the entities

Comment: I'm having the same issues, It might be related to nullable Guid? keys?  My other suspicion is a race condition.

Comment: I have this problem too. I had it about a year ago and it just went away, now it's back. Hundreds of `System.ArgumentException` thrown before finally working. It only does it the first time a query runs when starting the app. Subsequent queries don't suffer from it.